# Get items with Active == true only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I use MVC jqGrid to create grid and it's my code to fill grid

```
var jsonData = new
        {
            total = formTemplatePage.TotalEntriesCount / (pageSize + childrenCount) + 1,
            page = gridSettings.PageIndex,
            rows = (
                       gridData.Select(c => new
                       {
                           id = c.Item.Id,
                           cell = new[]
                                                                    {
                                                                        c.Number,
                                                                        c.Item.Name,
                                                                        c.Item.Id.ToString(), 
                                                                        c.Item.Active.ToString(),
                                                                        c.Level,
                                                                        c.ParentId,
                                                                        c.IsLeaf,
                                                                        c.Expanded,
                                                                        c.UnKnown,
                                                                    }
                       })).ToList()
        };
```

but how can I get `c.Item.Active == true` only?

Comment: wouldn't `gridData.Where(c => c.Item.Active).Select(...` be ok?

Comment: @allo_man I'm not sure

Comment: What is the behavior that this cause that you do not want?

Comment: I'm sorry, it actually works, thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change the select for rows to

```
gridData.Where(c => c.Item.Active).Select([...]);
```